# Bash file mass replacement

Tags: bash

If I am writing a bash script to do an inplace edit of a bunch of files and the line I want to change is something like:

`#include <foo/bar.h>`

to

`#include "bar.h"`

what would the syntax be?

```
old='#include <foo/bar.h>'
new='#include "bar.h'
perl -pe -i.bak 's/$old/$new/g' baz.h
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in bash, or in perl?  Your question says bash, but your example says perl.

Comment: It's part of a larger bash file that is grabbing bits from multiple files and changing things around. My problem is this one perl line that should preform an inplace edit of the file baz.h I think I need some escape characters or something in old and new

Comment: Yes, you'll have some escaping issues there, because your $old contains the `/` character.  If you use some other character as your regex terminator, that would work... perhaps 's@...@...@' as I used in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the files are in the same directory, this should work:

```
sed -e 's@#include <foo/bar.h>@#include "bar.h"@' -i *.c
```

Comment: `sed -e 's@$old@$new@' -i $current` doesn't seem to change anything in the target files. they still have the original lines.

Comment: If you're quoting variables, you'll probably need to use " instead of ' marks, or else the $old and $new will be substituted literally, instead of expanded.

Comment: @Newbie, use double quotes, not single quotes. Single quotes prevent the variables from being substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Bash

```
for file in *.c
do
  while read -r line
  do
      case "$line" in 
        *"$old"* ) line="${line/$old/$new}"
      esac
      echo "$line"
  done < "$file" > tempo && mv tempo "$file"  
done
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly work in the context of my larger program... It's running inside a few nested loops and the file it's working on is changing, as well as the values it's replacing.

Comment: That's also a really complicated way to do it... but it _is_ pure bash, unlike my answer... so if you really want a _bash_ answer, this one probably wins.

Comment: Not really complicated. The while loop is just the same as `sed 's/old/new/' file`. Put the while loop in a bash function and call this function `sed` and it works the same :)